# In python how can we append run time reults to a list?

Tags: python

how to write unit test case for python fibonacci series generation. I need to append the generated output in a list and then have to compare the list with the test case's sample list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best answer I can give with limited info:

```
result = []
for each in run_time_results:
    result.append(each)
```

Comment: This can be reduced to `result = []; result.extend(run_time_results)` or `result = [i for i in run_time_results]` or even `result = list(run_time_results)`.

Comment: i need an example to write unit test case for fibonacci series generation in python